# How to delete all schedules in node-schedule?

Tags: javascript, node.js, scheduled-tasks

I see from [docs](https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule) you can delete one by one by name for example ...

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

 // sample announcement

 var rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
 rule.dayOfWeek = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
 rule.minute = 50;
 rule.hour = 12;

 var message = schedule.scheduleJob("AnnouncementOne", rule, function() {
    // make my announcement
})

AnnouncementOne.cancel();
```

but I would like code to get all scheduled jobs and then loop through them to delete each one. I think the following gets all the jobs ...

```
var jobList = schedule.scheduledJobs;
```

which outputs following to console ...

```
{ 'AnnouncementOne':
   Job {
     job: [Function],
     callback: false,
     name: 'AnnouncementOne',
     trackInvocation: [Function],
     stopTrackingInvocation: [Function],
     triggeredJobs: [Function],
     setTriggeredJobs: [Function],
     cancel: [Function],
     cancelNext: [Function],
     reschedule: [Function],
     nextInvocation: [Function],
     pendingInvocations: [Function] },
  'AnnouncementTwo':
   Job {
     job: [Function],
     callback: false,
     name: 'AnnouncementTwo',
     trackInvocation: [Function],
     stopTrackingInvocation: [Function],
     triggeredJobs: [Function],
     setTriggeredJobs: [Function],
     cancel: [Function],
     cancelNext: [Function],
     reschedule: [Function],
     nextInvocation: [Function],
     pendingInvocations: [Function] } }
```

how do I loop through jobList to delete each job?

Alternative Code:

```
var jobList = schedule.scheduledJobs;

for(jobName in jobList){
  var job = 'jobList.' + jobName;
  eval(job+'.cancel()');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not the most elegant approach, but since jobList lacks a length field, here is a way to achieve this:

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

// sample announcement

var rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
rule.dayOfWeek = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
rule.minute = 50;
rule.hour = 12;

var message = schedule.scheduleJob("Announcement0", rule, function() {
    // make my announcement
})

var message = schedule.scheduleJob("Announcement1", rule, function() {
    // make my announcement
})

var jobList = schedule.scheduledJobs;

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   eval('jobList.Announcement'+i+'.cancel()');
}
```

This removes the scheduled jobs from the list.

To check whether a job exists prior to deleting it:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
  var job = 'jobList.Announcement'+i;
  if(eval(job) != undefined) {
    eval(job+'.cancel()');
  }
}
```

Of course, you can also use for-in.  Just remember that if you use for-in the results are not ordered while the results are ordered in the regular for loop, so you could potentially experience some unexpected behavior:

```
var jobList = schedule.scheduledJobs;

for(jobName in jobList){
  var job = 'jobList.' + jobName;
  eval(job+'.cancel()');
}
```

Comment: I get 

`    jobList.Announcement0.cancel()  
  
                      ^  
      
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'cancel' of undefined  
`

How would I test whether the job exists before trying to cancel it as I will not know for sure whether it exists or not, just want to delete it if it does.

Comment: You got this error because DeleteTesting0 does not exist in your list of jobs. I updated the answer with checking whether a job exists prior to deleting it.

Comment: Got it, thanks, btw, as an option, could I go through the object and delete each job with code like I added to bottom of question? I don't care if all jobs are deleted.

Comment: That's fine, just remember that if you use for-in the results are not ordered while the results are ordered in the regular for loop. So you may experience some unexpected behavior. From my experience I stay away from for-in in general, but my field is mostly working with JavaScript in front-end browser settings, where unexpected behavior is not afforded.

Comment: I'd be wary of using eval. Why not joblist['Announcement'+i].cancel() ?

Also, why doesn't scheduledJobs appear in node-schedule documentation?

Answer (score 7):

It is better to keep away from `eval`

```
const schedule = require('node-schedule');
const _ = require('lodash');
const j = schedule.scheduleJob('SomeDirtyWork', '42 * * * *', () => {
  // Something is going on
});

const jobNames = _.keys(schedule.scheduledJobs);
for(let name of jobNames) schedule.cancelJob(name);
```

Answer (score 3):

In one line:

```
for (const job in schedule.scheduledJobs) schedule.cancelJob(job);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var jobList = cron.scheduledJobs; //Get All scheduled jobs

Object.values(jobList).map(job => {
  console.log("Each Job", job.name);

    cron.cancelJob(job.name);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello I had same problem, But you can use below code.

```
var jobList = schedule.scheduledJobs;
for(jobName in jobList){
    // Here inside **jobName** you are getting name of each Schedule.
    var EachJobObject = cron.scheduledJobs[jobName];
    EachJobObject.cancel();
}
```

Above Code will cancel all Node Schedule. it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

you also can do this:

```
for (const job in schedule.scheduledJobs) schedule.scheduledJobs[job].cancel();
```